# Is it possible to embed one (or more) translations into a .PDF that is interactively accessible?

Tags: pdftex, embedding, interaction

Specifically for my Curriculum Vitae I find myself regularly creating it twice: Once in my native language, and a second time in English. I therefore have two .PDFs with the exact same layout, just translated.

I was wondering if there was the option to have a "Translate"-button embedded into the .PDF (To be precise, it would be more of a switch, as changing back and forth should be possible by clicking it again) that transitions between the two versions.

It doesn't even have to be a nice transition (Although ideal), just a hard cut from one .PDF to the other when clicking on a certain part of it (Just like it would open a web link with hyperlink).

Is this possible in pdfTeX and how?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It's not quite what you're looking for, but the `attachfile` file package would let you attach an English pdf to your native pdf.  Instead of a switch, it would open up the other pdf.

Comment: LaTeX packages providing pdf OCG (Optional Content Groups) support would help, for example [`ocgx2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2).